# Bindind DataTable with silverlight Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datatable

I am writing an app which is to be intranet based .I am trying to use silverlight with Ado.net Just like I write my aspx pages. BUt I have not found how to connect datatable generated from my class directly to my silverlight interfaces.

ANy tut that can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight cannot connect to a database directly, it only supports webservice access. Here are two links to get you started:

http://wildermuth.com/2009/09/29/Choosing_a_Data_Access_Layer_for_Silverlight_3

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/dataaccesssilverlightenabledwcfservice07152008013110am/dataaccesssilverlightenabledwcfservice.aspx

Or just google "silverlight data access" and you will get plenty of hits.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `DataTable`s, you may take a look at the [BindableDataGrid](http://slbindabledatagrid.codeplex.com/) project which includes these.

I however strongly recommend against. A better approach for dynamic data would perhaps be to use some kind of `DynamicEntity` class.